# Java operators precedence

Tags: java, operators

I have got confused due to what is true regarding the operator precedence in Java. I read in tutorials a long time ago that AND has a higher priority than OR, which is confirmed by the answers provided in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263660/in-java-what-are-the-boolean-order-of-operations). However, I am currently studying Java using the "Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide". This book contains the following example:

```
int y = 5;
int x = 2;
if ((x > 3) && (y < 2) | doStuff()) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

I am copying and citing the explanation of how the compiler handles the above code:

> `If (x > 3)` is `true`, and either `(y < 2)` or the result of
>   `doStuff()` is `true`, then print `"true"`. Because of the
>   short-circuit `&&`, the expression is evaluated as though there were
>   parentheses around `(y < 2) | doStuff()`. In other words, it is
>   evaluated as a single expression before the `&&` and a single
>   expression after the `&&`.

This implies though that `|` has higher precedence than `&&`. Is it that due to the use of the "non-short-circuit OR" and instead of the short circuit OR? What is true?

Comment: Probably a misprint in the book. A bitwise or b/w `(y<2)` and `doStuff()` doesn't make sense.

Besides, the explanation talks about "either y<2 is true or doStuff() is true", which is logical OR.

Comment: probably it's not bitwise OR, check it once again.

Comment: `|` isn't the same as `||`.  One is bitwise.  The other is logical.

Comment: Ok, false name, not "bitwise or" but "non-short-circuit OR".

Comment: Asking the obvious probably, but *what book*?

Comment: @owlstead: "Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide". Could you make a comment with regard to this book?

Comment: Simply for easier understanding I prefer to make some more brackets even if not necessary.

Comment: Tried to find errata on that book, but I didn't find any. Sun/Oracle hardly ever admit to mistakes anyway.

Comment: I have formatted your question, maybe you could check out the resulting [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) formatting. Please use 4 spaces instead of tabs for code fragments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because it is using the `|` operator instead of `||`, which has a higher priority. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) the table.

Use the `||` operator instead and it'll do what you think.

Comment: That said, the explanation of the book is completely wrong. The short-circuitness of the `&&` operator doen't have anything to do with why `(y < 2) | doStuff()` is evaluated as if there were parenthese around it.

Comment: @JB Nizet: The example was set on operators precedence not on how the && actually works. Surprisingly the book lacks a table presenting the whole precedence of the operators in this section, therefore got me confused according to my previous knowledge.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's a goofy example. Bottom line is the operator precedence table tells all

Comment: @arjacsoh: what I mean is that this sentence is wrong: *Because of the short-circuit &&, the expression is evaluated as though there were parentheses around (y < 2) | doStuff()*. It should in fact be: *Because | has a higher precedence than &&, the expression is evaluated as though there were parentheses around (y < 2) | doStuff()*.

Comment: Having a hard time seeing how this even compiles - does the boolean `(y < 2)` get auto-promoted to int?

Answer (score 0):

> Because of the short-circuit &&, the expression is evaluated as though there were parentheses around (y < 2) | doStuff() ...

This statement is incorrect, indeed meaningless. The fact that && is a short-circuit operator has nothing to do with the evaluation of (y < 2) | doStuff(), and indeed that could only compile if doStuff() returned a Boolean. What makes the difference (the implicit parentheses) is the *precedence* of && relative to |, which is defined in JLS ##15.22-23 as && being lower.