# Operators precedence in Java gets confusing

Tags: java, operators

I set a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058617/java-operators-precedence) a few weeks ago but I cannot still dissolve the ambiguity and the confusion on [java operators precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). This time I have this fragment of code:

```
int mask = 0;
int count = 0;
if( ((5<7) || (++count < 10)) | mask++ < 10 )   
    mask = mask + 1;
System.out.println(mask + " " + count);
```

The result is (unexpectedly to me): 2  0.

Moreover, the compiler provides a warning underlining only the expression (++count<10): dead code.

I reckon however  the execution of the code though as either one of the following ways:

1) | has a higher precedence than ||, hence it is considered as there were parenthesis around the expression ( (++count<10) | mask++ <10). This way the compiler should have executed the both parts and count should have been set to 1 (++count<10).

2) If the compiler looks first the (5<7) and after evaluating it to false skips the entire second expression, then mask should not have been increased and we would wait the value 1 in the output.

What have I misunderstood and cannot explain the behavior of the compiler, as well as the output?

Comment: You have additional parenthesis around the `||`. So your claim that `|` has higher precedence than `||` is irrelevant as you've placed additional parenthesis in your expression.

Comment: Parenthesis has the highest precedence, higher than `|`

Comment: Ok, you are right. How I did not noticed it?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||` is an `OR` operator that only evaluates its right hand side expression if the left hand side expression is false. In your case, `5 < 7` is true and `++count < 10` is not evaluated.

On the other hand, `|` always evaluates both expressions: even if `((5<7) || (++count < 10))` is true, `mask++ < 10` will be evaluated.

Comment: I totally agree. The misconception derives from not noticing the parenthensis around the first exp

Comment: @arjacsoh Ah ok - that makes a difference indeed.

Answer (score 0):

> | has a higher precedence than ||, hence it is considered as there were parenthesis around the expression ((++count<10) | mask++ <10).

There is no such expression in your code. Look again. The entire expression is `( ((5<7) || (++count < 10)) | mask++ < 10 )`. The `||` associates the constant test `5<7` with `++count < 10`, which can never be executed because the constant test is always false, and the `|` associates all that with `mask++ < 10`.

There is in fact no operator precedence problem here at all, just your own misunderstanding of where you have put your parentheses.