# Using 'and' and 'or' in an if/else PHP statement

Tags: php

I am attempting to use both AND and OR statements in my IF/ELSE statement, but I cannot get the desired effect.

What I would like to achieve is that if either 'a' or 'b' has a value of '1' but both 'c' and 'd' must be 1 then I get 'Yes'.

All my attempts have given me either 'Yes' or have not worked (blank screen).

```
<?php
$a = "0";
$b = "1";
$c = "1";
$d = "1";
if (($a == "1") || ($b == "1") && ($c == "1") && ($d == "1")) {
    echo "Yes";
    }
    else {
    echo "No";
    }

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use parenthesis the same way, you'd use them in math.

Comment: Incidentally, the parentheses around the equality expressions aren't really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need and extra parenthesis, to make sure the evaluation order will be done correctly, like in math:

```
if (  (  ($a == "1") || ($b == "1")  ) && ($c == "1") && ($d == "1")) {
      ^                              ^
```

That way, let's say for example:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 1;
$d = 2;
```

The first parenthesis will be evaluated as `true || false`. The final result will be `true`.

So now you have `true && ($c == "1") && ($d == "1")`

`$c = 1`, so again, the next evaluation will be `true && true && ($d == 1)`

`$d = 2`, so the next round will be `true && true && false`, final result, in this example, will be `false`.

Comment: That's the chap! Thank you @Felippe Will accept answer when allowed (in 11 minutes!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parenthesis.

Why?

Because inner parenthesis are evaluated first before outer parenthesis.  Take this example:

`((1 == 1 && (2 == 2)) || 3 == 3)`

What will be evaluated first?  The 2 == 2 then the 1 == 1 and then the 3 == 3.  In your if condition, because you are mixing AND's and OR's, you will not get the desired affect.

`( (($a == "1") || ($b == "1")) && ($c == "1") && ($d == "1") )`

Should work for you.  In fact you can do this so that it looks even better:

`(($a == 1 || $b == 1) && $c == 1 && $d == 1)`

Because it is not necessary to put 1 in quotes ie: `"1"`.  PHP's truthiness will evaluate `1 == "1"` to be true.  However if you wanted to check for an actual string that contains 1, then you would use the `===` operator.

```
$a = 1;
$b = "1"
$a == "1";  // true
$b == 1;    // true
$a === "1"; // false
$b === "1"; // true
```

However for more information go here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 0):

The equality operators will be evaluated first, then &&, then ||. Parentheses will be evaluated before anything else, so adding them can change the order.

Check the answer [In Java, what are the boolean "order of operations"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263660/in-java-what-are-the-boolean-order-of-operations)

Answer (score 0):

It will always echo a Yes because PHP interpreter places The AND operation before the OR operation.

So your if statement interpretes like this:

`If 
    a = 1 or b = 1 and c = 1 and d = 1 
    then 
        echo 'Yes' 
else
    echo 'No'`

That's why you always get a yes..