# Java: OR Operator after AND in "If" Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, operators

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263692) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917) answer Java employs short circuiting with regard to `&&` and `||` operators. It also gives `&&` higher precedence over `||`. Yet the following code evaluates to `true`:

```
    boolean condition1 = true;
    boolean condition2 = true;
    boolean condition3 = true;

    if ( !condition3 && condition1 || condition2 ) {
        System.out.println("Condition is true"); // prints Condition is true
    }
```

Since `condition3` is set to `true` this should cause `!condition3` to be false so why is Java even checking `condition1`?

If I add parentheses around the first condition it still evaluates to true:

```
    if ( (!condition3) && condition1 || condition2 ) {
        System.out.println("Condition is true");
    }
```

I understand why this code evaluates to true:

```
    if ( condition1 || condition2 && !condition3) {
        System.out.println("Condition is true");
    }
```

Because once Java encounters the `||` after `condition1` it doesn't even bother checking the following conditions. But I don't understand why the first two examples evaluate to true.

My goal is to require `condition3` to be false and then have *either* `conditon1` or `condition2` (or both) to be true (but if `condition3` is `true` then I don't want print statement to execute regardless of how `condition1` and `condition2` evaluate)

Thanks

Comment: *"My goal is to require condition3 to be false and then have either conditon1 or condition2 (or both) to be true"* `if ((!condition3)&&(condition1||condition2))`

Comment: OK so I missed parentheses around  `condition1 || condition2 `. But why is it not sufficient (to give `!condition3` higher precedence)  to add parentheses only around  `!condition3 ` ?

Comment: "higer precedence" means that this parts "stay closer" then the rest. The *result* of `&&` becomes one side of the `||`

Answer (score 10):

You said:

> It also gives && higher precedence over ||.

which means `!condition3 && condition1` will be evaluated first.

So this

```
!condition3 && condition1 || condition2
```

equals:

```
(!condition3 && condition1) || condition2
```

since `condition2` is `true`, the expression is `true`.