# What is difference between using logical operators using parentheses?

Tags: java, logical-operators, parentheses

I am getting different results: -1 if I use parentheses and 1 if I don't use parentheses.

For test case "30/10/2019" I am getting -1 if I use parentheses and 1 if I don't use parentheses in the following line:

```
else if((mm==1||mm==3||mm==5||mm==7||mm==8||mm==10||mm==12) && mm<13 && mm>0 && dd>0 && dd<32) return 1;
```

What is the difference between above line and below line?

```
else if(mm==1||mm==3||mm==5||mm==7||mm==8||mm==10||mm==12 && mm<13 && mm>0 && dd>0 && dd<32) return 1;
```

```
public class Utility {
   public static int checkDate(String date){
     String []st;
   if((date.charAt(2)=='.' && date.charAt(5)=='.')||(date.charAt(2)=='/' && date.charAt(5)=='/')||(date.charAt(2)=='-' && date.charAt(5)=='-'))
   {
       String token = Character.toString(date.charAt(2));
       if(date.charAt(2) == '.') st = date.split("\\.");
       else st = date.split(token);

       int dd = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
       int mm = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);
       int yy = Integer.parseInt(st[2]);

        if(mm == 2 && dd>0 && dd<30 && mm<13 && mm>0) return 1;

        else if((mm==1||mm==3||mm==5||mm==7||mm==8||mm==10||mm==12) && mm<13 && mm>0 && dd>0 && dd<32) return 1;

        else if((mm==4||mm==6||mm==9||mm==11) && dd>0 && dd<31 && mm<13 && mm>0) return 1;

        else return -1;
   }
   else return -1;
 }
}

import java.util.Scanner;


public class DateValidation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // STUDENT CODE BEGINS HERE
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String dt=sc.next();
    Utility ut = new Utility();
    int flag = ut.checkDate(dt);
    if(flag==1)
        System.out.println("Valid");
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid");
       // STUDENT CODE ENDs HERE

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, what are the boolean "order of operations"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263660/in-java-what-are-the-boolean-order-of-operations)

Comment: same as with any operator `(1 + 2) * 3 == 9` and `1 + 2 * 3 == 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses decide the order these booleans are resolved. *And* binds stronger than *Or*. In your case you ask for:

```
mm==12 && mm<13
```

So left comparison and right comparison must resolve to true. They don't, as you are in month 10. With parenthesis you decide to check if your month value is valid at all, this resolves to true, and then the `&&` check resolves to true as well.

Answer (score 1):

It will execute the following (in highest order of precedence):

- Parentheses `()`
- Not `!`
- And `&&`
- Or `||`

```
else if((mm==1||mm==3||mm==5||mm==7||mm==8||mm==10||mm==12) && mm<13 && mm>0 && dd>0 && dd<32) 
    return 1;
```

It will evaluate `(mm==1||mm==3||mm==5||mm==7||mm==8||mm==10||mm==12)` first, then `&& mm<13 && mm>0 && dd>0 && dd<32`

```
else if(mm==1||mm==3||mm==5||mm==7||mm==8||mm==10||mm==12 && mm<13 && mm>0 && dd>0 && dd<32) 
    return 1;
```

As for the other, it will evaluate `mm<13 && mm>0 && dd>0 && dd<32` first, then `mm==1||mm==3||mm==5||mm==7||mm==8||mm==10||mm==12 &&`

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example.

```java
      int a = 5;

      System.out.println((a == 5 || a == 10) && a == 8 || a == 9); // false
      // evaluates to    true && false || false which is false

      System.out.println(a == 5 || a == 10 && a == 8 || a == 9);  // true
      // evaluate to true || false && false && false
      // the first true, wins because it is followed by an || so the whole
      // expression evaluates to true.
```

With `a && b` both both `a` and `b` must be `true` for the statement to be `true`
With `a || b` only one of `a` and `b` must be `true`.

This also goes for grouped expressions.

If one expression is `true` and the other is `false`, the complete expression is `false` for `&&` and true for `||`.  These operators work from left to right so you need to group appropriately, just like arithmetic expressions.

The best advice is always use parentheses to ensure proper evaluation of expressions.